# access denied using mkdir and rmdir in jenkins

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, mkdir, access-denied, rmdir

Jenkins is generating a build of a C++ project made in Visual Studio.

During the process, some `.bat`s are called and in one of them, there is a structure like this:

```
SET TEMPDIR=Temp
rmdir %TEMPDIR% /S /Q
echo Don't continue if there was an error above (except the not found error which is ok) and go hand delete the dir!
:pause
mkdir %TEMPDIR%
```

I'm not very familiar to batch scripting, but when both `rmdir` and `mkdir` are called, Jenkins gives me `access denied`.

I looked in the build configurations to search for any type of read/write permissions but it seems there isn't any.

How can I fix this? Later the other scripts try to access `Temp` but they fail and it breaks my build.

Comment: `Temp` is a relative path, so what is it related to?

Comment: Didn't quite get what you mean. `Temp` is the true name of a folder referenced by the variable `TEMPDIR`. `Temp` is used to store the binaries that are generated by visual studio during the build process. As it gives me `access denied`, the folder isn't created and the build breaks.

Comment: `Temp` is a literal that is assigned to `TEMPDIR`, not the value contained in `%Temp%`, so it is a relative path from `%CWD%`.  Does the Jenkins process have privileges in wherever its `%CWD%` is located?

Comment: The usual problem of people refusing to tell windows where it wants stuff. We use known paths in programming not random paths as you are using.

Comment: Can someone please clarify the difference between `TEMPDIR` and `%TEMPDIR%`? As I said, I'm not an expert in batch syntax and this seems to be meaningful in this situation. I was thinking that all I needed was to add an extra line granting permissions.

Comment: You use the `%VAR%` form to read the value stored in `VAR`. `%CWD%` is a built-in `cmd.exe` pseudo environment variable.

Comment: `rmdir %TEMPDIR% /S /Q` removes a directory (not sure why you are doing this as you attempt to recreate it straight away) relative to the current directory (where ever that is - it changes on HOW you start your program).

Comment: Well, I mean, `Temp` is only a folder name, it is not specified on which drive it resides and under what path...

Comment: It is located in `C:\Users\Daniel\...`.

Comment: `rmdir "C:\Users\Daniel\Temp" /s /q` will delete that folder, and it will always find it.

Comment: What is the difference? For example, suppose I write `rmdir "C:\Users\Daniel\Temp" /s /q`, you say it's gonna work. But if I am at `C:\Users\Daniel` and I write `rmdir %TEMPDIR% /S /Q`, what would the difference be for the first case work and the second not?

Comment: Don't do it like that anyways, step into Temp, by making it your current directory, then remove it and it's subdirectories. Then you can step back out of it again. It may even help with your situation because, the problem may be permission based only on `Temp`. You can use either `CD "Temp"`, `RD /S/Q "Temp"`, `CD ..` or `PushD "Temp"`, `RD /S/Q "Temp"`, `PopD`.

Comment: Correction, the above should be `RD /S/Q "."`, or `RD /S/Q "%CD%".

Comment: @Compo, I don't think you can ever delete the current directory.

Comment: That was exactly the point of my comment, @jdwdonahue. It removes every file and directory within but leaves the current directory in tact, _because it cannot remove the current directory_.

Comment: @Compo, my apologies!  I did eventually grok your intentions there.

Comment: I suspect the OP's build configuration/scripts are poorly written and we won't be able to resolve this issue without a more complete picture of what is going on.  The OP says the scripts are generated, so what can be done?  Reverse engineer the build system, find and fix all of its flaws!

Comment: In programming we don't care and don' bother to look up relative paths as we don't use them. There's a whole pile of ways of working out absolute paths relative to something we look up.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the reasons `rmdir` can fail:

- No permissions
- The directory contains files.
- It's the current working directory of one or more processes.
- A process has a lock on it.

Some the reasons `mkdir` can fail:

- No permissions
- The directory already exists.

The OP's script is attempting to create a directory named "Temp" in whatever the `%CD%` is for the process running that script.  If there are other processes that also run that script, or any that avail themselves of the same `%CD%\Temp` path for any reason, then there can be failures for both creating or deleting that path.

---

It is common in build systems, for there to be multiple parallel processes and threads running a variety of programs/scripts in a variety of working directories. From the perspective of any instance of a `cmd` file, any path that is `%CD%` relative, is effectively random.  All descent CI build systems provide environment variables that such programs/scripts can use to orient themselves correctly, relative to a known build root of some form, often called something like `BuildRoot`.

But the real issue here is how the OP's scripts are handling temp directory management.  They simply aren't robust enough to be sharing a common temp directory.

---

I would add that a good CI build system, provides some form of per-process/thread temp directory, that programs/scripts can use without having to do any directory management.

Comment: I think those `.bat`s are automatically generated by visual studio.

Comment: @Daniel, you probably have custom build steps, or some of your build process is defined by the packages you are using.