# mkdir immediatly after rmdir gives me access denied

Tags: batch-file, mkdir, rmdir

I have a folder (let's call it `F`).

I wrote a batch file that does

```
rmdir F /S /Q
mkdir F
```

When I call the mkdir `F`, it gives me access denied, probably because the system may be still deleting `F`. How can I do to deal with this problem?

Comment: Use full paths. I don't know why you would expect that to work.

Comment: Daniel, please read [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59912113/access-denied-using-mkdir-and-rmdir-in-jenkins#comment105951564_59912113) to your other/previous question.

Comment: In fact, `rmdir` doesn't give me any error, but when I call `mkdir` right after, it gives me that access denied error. I read your comment but it got me confused. Why would I enter a folder to remove it?

Comment: Because the removal will not happen if you're inside it, but its content will be removed! Just try it, I gave you the three lines to use, and did so using two methods.

Comment: But in the moment I remove, I am not inside. I'm in the parent folder.

Comment: @Daniel - You can't delete a folder that you're inside. https://i.imgur.com/lcPQ50M.png

Comment: You are when you use the `CD` or `PushD` command I specifically told you to use, _and the phrase "Step in", should have given you the clue too!_ It's just three commands, I gave you them, it's not removing `Temp`, so you don't have to make it again, _(I didn't tell you to use `MD` or `MkDir`, for a reason)_.

Comment: If you want to remove F, just `rd /s /q F`.

Comment: What environment is this test script running in?

Comment: Running in a windows 10.

Comment: In what environment in Windows 10?  In what directory are you running this script?

Comment: I give up.  There's no possible path named C:/User/Danial/... that I can think of on any Windows system.  Windows uses backslashes.  I can `md F & rd /s /q F & md F & rd /s /q F` all day long in almost any directory on my system.  Your issue is environmental in nature and you either don't know that it is, or you are concealing it from us.

Comment: My bad, I changed the slash direction. C:\Users\Daniel\ParentOfF.

Comment: You don't understand.  What's in the `\...\` part of that path?  There's no triple dots in a legal path, but it's often used to obfuscate or just shorten a path string when it's contents aren't relevant.  But they might be in this case.

Comment: Edited. It meant there was subfolders between Daniel and ParentOfF but suppose it doesn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206643/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-daniel).

Comment: Triple dots are legal in Win9x and in MSDos on Novell. They are a Novell operating system thing and means parent of parent. You can use as many dots as you like. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160202-00/?p=92953

Answer (score 1):

Is this better for you to understand?

```bat
CD "F" 2>NUL && (
    RD /S/Q "." 2>NUL
    CD ..
) || (
    MD "F" 2>NUL
) || (
    Echo Cannot create F
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >NUL
)
```

Or this?

```bat
PushD "F" 2>NUL && (
    RD /S/Q "." 2>NUL
    PopD
) || (
    MD "F" 2>NUL
) || (
    Echo Cannot create F
    Timeout 3 /NoBreak >NUL
)
```

Comment: If `F` doesn't exist, what happens when I run this? Are the 2 possibilities you wrote the exact same?

Comment: I've made a small modification, for that possibility. If `F` doesn't exist, you should be able to create it, subject to you having the relevant permissions to do so, and the drive being writeable.